# How to set Gradle transitive dependency version?

Tags: gradle

In our project we are using the following Groovy dependency:

```
compile("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8")
```

The issue is that this dependency has multiple transitive dependencies, one of them is:

```
org.apache.ant:ant 1.9.13
```

which has some vulnerabilities and needs to get upgrade to version 1.10.8 which they got fixed at.
When I upgrade the parent groovy-all:2.5.8 to the latest version I can still see it gets the problematic org.apache.ant:ant 1.9.13 dependency:

```
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.6
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.6 -> 2.5.10
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:3.0.6 -> 2.5.10
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.10
|    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.13
```

Is there any way forcing Gradle to brings back the version I need?

Comment: Are you by chance using the Spring Dependency Management plugin? Gradle doesn't downgrade versions by itself, so there must be something else messing with your dependencies.

Comment: I get around this by adding the desired version of dependencies to the list of dependencies i.e. adding org.apache.ant:ant:1.10.8 - not sure if this overrides the dependency but our commercial scanning tools are happy with this so I hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Enforce Version**

You can override transitive dependency versions with gradle (see: [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version)) using the constraints keyword:

```
constraints {
    implementation('org.apache.ant:ant') {
        version {
            require '1.10.12'
            reject '1.9.13'
        }

        because('Versions < 1.10.11 got several vulnerabilities: CVE-2021-36374, CVE-2021-36373, CVE-2020-11979')
    }
}
```

**Verify**

The easiest way to verify that the dependency enforcement is working will be as follows:

```
./gradlew -q dependencyInsight --dependency ant
```

You'll then see something like this, indicating the accomplished upgrade of the version.

```
org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.13 -> 1.10.12
```